# Entity Framework 4.0 2 many-to-many with same entities

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have 2 entities (say `People` and `Books`) that have two many-to-many relationships.  I have created two different linking tables - e.g. the linking tables are called `BooksCheckedOutByPeople` and `BooksOnHoldByPeople`.

EF 4.0 correctly makes two relationships.  It calls them something like `PeopleBooks` and `PeopleBooks1`.

When I am making Linq queries, how do I tell Linq to use a specific one of these relationships?  Is there any way in Linq to specify one relationship instead of the other?

Say I'm creating a query against `People` and I want to get the `Books` for `BooksCheckedOutByPeople` and thus I need to use the relationship `PeopleBooks`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rename "PeopleBooks" and "PeopleBooks1" to more informative property names by editing the model EF generates for you. Something like "BooksOnHold" and "BooksCheckedOut".

At that point, when writing your LINQ queries, just reference the right navigation properties (as they're called). LINQ uses whichever properties you specify, and the Entity Framework should generate a unique navigation property for each collection.

**Edit**

I just fired up VS2010 to copy your model and poke around a bit.

I see that EF4 did indeed generate two *Navigation Properties* foor Book and Person, called People and People1, and Books and Books1 (respectively).

If you select any of these Navigation Properties in the Model Browser and look at the Properties pane, you should be able to see which table is correlated to that association and rename the property appropriately. Here's a screenshot from my PC: [image: screenshot]

You can see that I've selected the "People" nav property for the "Book" entity. The association in this case is determined by BooksCheckedOutByPeople, so I can rename the property to "PeopleCheckingOut", or something more useful than "People". When I'm using LINQ-to-Entities later, I then reference the "PeopleCheckingOut" property to query that collection on any specific Book.